# Change the text size of the series name in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

How can I make the text "Balances of 2014" larger in this case ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look here http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.html#setLegendTextSize%28float%29:

```
Renderer.setLegendTextSize(value);
```